# How to represent a number in the form of A*10-^n?

Tags: vb.net

I recently wrote this program in Visul Basic 13.
it searchs for the nth catalan number but after 48 even Decimal type is too short.
Is there any other way to represent them? like in the form of A*10^n?

```
Public Class Try_Catalan_Number

    'Catalan numbers form a sequence of natural numbers that occur in various counting problems,
    'often involving recursively defined objects.

    Inherits Base_Number

    Public Overrides Sub Test()

        Dim Return_Catalan_Value As Decimal

        If Function_Catalan(Return_Catalan_Value) = False Then

            Return_To_Form_Boolean = False
        Else

            Return_To_Form_Boolean = True

        End If

        Return_To_Form_Value = Function_Catalan(Return_Catalan_Value)

    End Sub

    Private Function Function_Catalan(Return_Catalan_Value As Decimal) As Decimal

        'We return a Decimal function because catalan numbers can be very big and decimal is the biggest type.

        Dim Binomial_Cofficients As Decimal
        Dim Result As Decimal
        Dim Number_Of_Loops As Integer
        Dim tmpNumber As Object
        Dim K As Decimal
        Dim N As Decimal

        If (Number > 48) Then

            Return False
            Exit Function

        End If

        '48 is the largest catalan number position which can be displayed...any position above 48 is too big.

        tmpNumber = Number - 1
        N = 2 * tmpNumber
        K = tmpNumber

        Result = 1

        For Number_Of_Loops = 1 To K

            Result = Result * (N - (K - Number_Of_Loops))
            Result = Result / Number_Of_Loops

        Next Number_Of_Loops

        Binomial_Cofficients = Result
        tmpNumber = Number - 1
        tmpNumber = ((1 / (1 + tmpNumber)) * Binomial_Cofficients)
        Return_Catalan_Value = tmpNumber

        Return Return_Catalan_Value

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Please, use the **COMMENTS** and **EDIT** to communicate. Not ANSWERS... this is **NOT** a forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I assume by "Visul Basic 13" you mean the VB which is associated with Visual Studio 2013, i.e. VB version 12.0.]

You can use [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) (you'll have to add a reference to System.Numerics):

```
Imports System.Numerics

Module Module1

    Friend Function Factorial(n As Integer) As BigInteger
        If n < 2 Then Return 1
        If n = 2 Then Return 2
        Dim f As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("2")
        For i = 3 To n
            f *= i
        Next
        Return f
    End Function

    Friend Function CatalanNumber(n As Integer) As BigInteger
        Return Factorial(2 * n) / (Factorial(n + 1) * Factorial(n))
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        For i = 0 To 550
            Console.WriteLine(CatalanNumber(i).ToString())
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

I did not test to see the maximum Catalan number it can calculate, and I have no inclination to verify the results beyond those shown on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Optimisations are left as an exercise for the reader ;)

**Edit**: FWIW, I can get it to run a bit faster by using

```
Function CatalanNumber(n As Integer) As BigInteger
    Dim nFactorial = Factorial(n)
    Dim twonFactorial = nFactorial
    For i = (n + 1) To 2 * n
        twonFactorial = BigInteger.Multiply(twonFactorial, i)
    Next
    Return twonFactorial / (BigInteger.Pow(nFactorial, 2) * (n + 1))
End Function
```

The speed increase varies from roughly 50% (*n*=50) to 20% (*n*=5000). If you're only using the function a few times for fairly small *n*, there may be little point worrying about it.

**Edit2** Re-writing your function a bit to make it easier to read and removing the off-by-one error, we get:

```
Private Function Function_Catalan(a As Integer) As BigInteger

    If a = 0 Then Return 1

    Dim binomialCofficient As BigInteger = BigInteger.One
    Dim n As Integer = 2 * a
    Dim k As Integer = a - 1

    For i As Integer = 1 To k
        binomialCofficient = binomialCofficient * (n - (k - i)) / i
    Next i

    Return binomialCofficient / a

End Function
```

Comment: Does the type Object contain BigInteger in it??

Comment: @user3450310 If your variables are ending up with a type of `Object` then you probably have `Option Infer Off` set somewhere. This will be *horrible* from a performance point of view. Simply declare the variable types explicitly to regain performance.

Answer (score 1):

to get this format you could use:

```
String.Format("{0:E4}", InputNumber)
```